# javascript mocking a prototype function error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a a case where I wanted to mock a function if some condition is met and I'm receiving an error.

here is the function that conditionally chooses whether to mock the function

```
MyClass.prototype.methodOne = function (callback) {
  var self = this;
  var methodTwo = this.methodTwo;
  if (someCondition) {
    methodTwo = function(callback) {
      callback(null);
    };
  }
  methodTwo(function (err) { });
}

MyClass.prototype.methodTwo = function (callback) {
  var self = this;
  var batch = new Batch();
  batch.concurrency(this.options.concurrency); ----> error here
  // some more stuff
  callback(err);
}
```

The error message is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concurrency' of undefined`

If instead of calling `methodTwo(function (err) { });` I call `this.methodTwo(function (err) { });` everything works fine.

Comment: Can you add some alerts or console.log into your example and tell what is your expacted behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var methodTwo = this.methodTwo;
```

When assigning a method to a variable, the function loses its context and `this` no longer refers to the original object. Try this:

```
MyClass.prototype.methodOne = function (callback) {
  if (someCondition) {
    this.methodTwo = function(callback) {
      callback(null);
    };
  }
  this.methodTwo(function (err) { });
}
```

If you don't want to override `methodTwo` permanently, use `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
MyClass.prototype.methodOne = function(callback) {
    var methodTwo = this.methodTwo.bind(this);
    if (someCondition) {
        methodTwo = function(callback) {
            callback(null);
        };
    }
    methodTwo(function(err) {
    });
}
```

For e.g.,

```
var o = {
  a: 'asdf',
  oMethod: function () {
    return this.a;
  }
};
```

Here, if you assign `oMethod` to a variable, invoking it would result in `undefined`

```
var oMethod = o.oMethod;
oMethod(); //undefined

var oMethod = o.oMethod.bind(o);
oMethod(); //asdf
```

Comment: I'm not sure if he wants rewrite `methodTwo` for this instance permamently.

Comment: Thanks - I actually tried bind first but was accidentally binding it to the callback - doh `methodTwo(function(err){}.bind(this))`